# How do I mark values ​in a series according to a specific rule?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to find positive and negative waves in my Serie. So how do I mark the data? 
**Example**
My Data:

```
| date                | value |
|---------------------|-------|
| 2018-09-06 00:00:03 | 0     |
| 2018-09-06 00:00:04 | 0     |
| 2018-09-06 00:00:05 | 1     |
| 2018-09-06 00:00:06 | 1     |
| 2018-09-06 00:00:07 | 2     |
| 2018-09-06 00:00:08 | -1    |
| 2018-09-06 00:00:09 | -5    |
| 2018-09-06 00:00:10 | 0     |
| 2018-09-06 00:00:11 | -6    |
| 2018-09-06 00:00:12 | 2     |
| 2018-09-06 00:00:13 | 0     |
| 2018-09-06 00:00:14 | 4     |
```

the result I want:

```
| date                | value | sign |
|---------------------|-------|------|
| 2018-09-06 00:00:03 | 0     | 1    |
| 2018-09-06 00:00:04 | 0     | 1    |
| 2018-09-06 00:00:05 | 1     | 1    |
| 2018-09-06 00:00:06 | 1     | 1    |
| 2018-09-06 00:00:07 | 2     | 1    |
| 2018-09-06 00:00:08 | -1    | 2    |
| 2018-09-06 00:00:09 | -5    | 2    |
| 2018-09-06 00:00:10 | 0     | 2    |
| 2018-09-06 00:00:11 | -6    | 2    |
| 2018-09-06 00:00:12 | 2     | 3    |
| 2018-09-06 00:00:13 | 0     | 3    |
| 2018-09-06 00:00:14 | 4     | 3    |
```

and then:

```py
mydata.groupby(['sign']).transform('sum')
```

Comment: what happens if your data has `1 0 0 -1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sample data does not include the case where positive and negative waves are separated by zeros, e.g. `1 0 0 -1`. Here's a solution that covers the case:

```
# mask the zeros
s = mydata['value'].eq(0)

# merge the zeros to the wave after them
m = np.sign(mydata['value']).mask(s).bfill()

# result
mydata['sign'] = m.diff().ne(0).cumsum()
```

Comment: Hello, Quang Hoang. Thank you for solving my problem. It worked!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) + [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
mydata['sign']=(mydata['value']*mydata['value'].shift()<0).cumsum()+1
print(mydata)

                   date  value  sign
0   2018-09-06-00:00:03      0     1
1   2018-09-06-00:00:04      0     1
2   2018-09-06-00:00:05      1     1
3   2018-09-06-00:00:06      1     1
4   2018-09-06-00:00:07      2     1
5   2018-09-06-00:00:08     -1     2
6   2018-09-06-00:00:09     -5     2
7   2018-09-06-00:00:10      0     2
8   2018-09-06-00:00:11     -6     2
9   2018-09-06-00:00:12      2     3
10  2018-09-06-00:00:13      0     3
11  2018-09-06-00:00:14      4     3
```

---

then you can get the series or columns you need with `transform`:

```
mydata[['sum_value','sum_sign']]=mydata.groupby(['sign'])[['value','sign']].transform('sum')
print(mydata)
                   date  value  sign  sum_value  sum_sign
0   2018-09-06-00:00:03      0     1          4         5
1   2018-09-06-00:00:04      0     1          4         5
2   2018-09-06-00:00:05      1     1          4         5
3   2018-09-06-00:00:06      1     1          4         5
4   2018-09-06-00:00:07      2     1          4         5
5   2018-09-06-00:00:08     -1     2        -12         8
6   2018-09-06-00:00:09     -5     2        -12         8
7   2018-09-06-00:00:10      0     2        -12         8
8   2018-09-06-00:00:11     -6     2        -12         8
9   2018-09-06-00:00:12      2     3          2         6
10  2018-09-06-00:00:13      0     3          2         6
```

Comment: Hello @ansev. Thank you for your reply. I checked your code. But the output has errors. If you want to examine the result: https://laureateemea-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/ugur_eren_bilgi_edu_tr/EVzcvmpMOjlHgGYHpjgp7HgBB8oPT5-9qceBwSgPR0DEHw?e=YPeF6L